# Add link on Bootstrap page?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I need to insert a link (opening on the same page) to another page on that selected "block". What is the best way to do it?

[Check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JitCS.jpg)

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <div class="align"><em class="icon-cubes sev_icon"></em></div>
        <h2>General Cargo </h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Wrap it in an anchor tag <a>. What do you mean by "that selected block"? You are supposed to attempt the solution yourself and then show us your code so we can help. Please post your code.

Comment: As @CZorio said, you should really post your code and not an image, so that we can help debug without having to re-write that code ourselves before we even begin helping.

Comment: @Pumizo did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `<div>` in an `<a>` (anchor) tag with a `href` pointing to the page you want to visit.

```
<a href="/your-page-link">
  <div class="span3">
    <div class="align"><em class="icon-cubes sev-icons"></em></div>
    <h2>General Cargo </h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Your reply worked, but it messed icon and text formatting. Any advice?
https://pl.vc/3w4aj